# Is it possible to have a magnet which looks like a hollow cylinder and who's north is interior and south is exterior?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Is it possible to have a magnet which looks like a hollow cylinder and who's north is interior and south is exterior?  What then happens as the cylinder gets longer?  Would that affect the strength of the magnetic field?

```
 Cut side view:       .  Approximated axial view:
                      .  
       South          .       South
   ______________     .       _____ 
  |______________|    .     / _____ \ 
                      .    / /     \ \
       North          .   | | North | |
   ______________     .    \ \_____/ /
  |______________|    .     \ _____ /
       South          .       South
```

I think it should be possible, but when extruding it longer, its properties get fuzzy to me.  I would assume that there would be a lot of stress on the structure as it gets longer, to try and break the cylinder apart.  ***EDIT** But what would happen to the strength of the field as the cylinder got longer?  Would the field strength at the ends of the cylinder get stronger or approach a maximum?*

Further, what would happen if the cylinder became bent around so that the ends touch?  Would there only be a south visible on the outside?  AFAIK, there must be a magnetic field line that goes from the south to the north from the same physical object, so would that mean that the field would try and reenter the physical object and cancel out the field?  *(**EDIT** According to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/54615/what-happens-to-the-magnetic-field-in-this-case/54630#54630) post, it would cancel out)*

Also, what would happen to the field lines as the ends approach each other?  Is there some way of visualizing the field as this occurs?  A sim programme perhaps?

Comment: Hi Adrian, and welcome to Physics SE. [This post](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/54615/what-happens-to-the-magnetic-field-in-this-case/54630#54630) is extremely related to yours, and might be of your interest.

Comment: The field cancels itself: http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/75115/730

Comment: Thanks @Ali, very interesting post.  But what happens if I didn't bend the cylinder ends together and merely lengthened it?  I was reading the discussion, but I'm not clear on that matter.  Would it strengthen the field lines at the end of the cylinder up to some maximum no matter how long the cylinder became?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18115/2451 and links therein.