# Doughnut magnet

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-monopoles

Take a magnet. Punch it flat so you now have a foil with a north side and a south side. Bend into a tube, so north is outside and south is inside. Finally bend the tube into a doughnut.

Will the doughnut behave like a magnetic monopole? If not: Why not?

Comment: It won't be a magnetic monopole. Not sure I understand your shapes though. Is your doughnut hollow?

Comment: Yes the doughnut is hollow - like a tire tube. Can you explain _why_ it will not be a magnetic monopole?

Comment: It won't be a monopole because it still has *two* poles.

Comment: I don't think you'd be able to do the final bend to make it a tube. Not perfectly, at least. The cylinder shape would have all of the inflowing field lines coming through the open ends. That would make the two ends very repulsive to one another

Comment: @KyleKanos will it _behave_ like a monopole? If not: why not?

Comment: I think you should look up more on how magnetism works and is created.

Comment: if you were to bring the two ends together, it would be like bringing two south poles of a magnet together. It would never perfectly align. There would be small imperfections that would allow the field lines to emerge

Comment: @jhobbie My teacher could not explain why this would not be a magnetic monopole, and could not point to any reading material that would. Can you?

Comment: Otherwise, you must ask where the field lines going to the south pole inside your donut originate. They cannot cross other lines and they cannot come from nowhere. The net flux of magnetic field lines through a surface surrounding your new donut cannot have changed through the entire process from bar magnet to donut

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens to the magnetic field in this case?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54615/)

Comment: @ChrisWhite Yep, which seems to conclude that "the field outside must vanish everywhere".

Comment: makes sense. You force the south pole's lines up through the surface, which then immediately cancel the north pole's lines

Answer (score 2):

You start the entire process with a magnet that has no net flux of magnetic field through a closed surface that surrounds it. The net flux of magnetic field through a closed surface, much like the net flux of an electric field, is independent of the shape of a source of the field inside the surface. That is, punching the magnet flat, rolling it up, and even twisting the magnet around cannot change the net amount of magnetic field flowing through an arbitrary closed surface around the magnet, which happens to be zero for a magnetic dipole. For it to become a magnetic monopole, the amount of magnetic field through an arbitrary surface must change spontaneously from zero to some non-zero amount. Since nothing is added to what is inside the surface, then the divergence theorem would ensure that there cannot be a difference in the flux before and after we have contorted the magnet. Since a magnetic monopole has non-zero flux and a regular magnet has zero flux, thus it cannot be reshaped into a monopole.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the same question as "If you have two bar magnets and were able to somehow fuse the two south ends together, would you then have a magnetic monopole" or something. Magnetism on a molecular level works by the particular alignment of particles. Those particles are not locked in place and can be realigned. That's why something that isn't magnetic can be magnetized, demagnetized, and remagnetized.

Comment: @ChrisWhite points to http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/54615/what-happens-to-the-magnetic-field-in-this-case which concludes that "the field outside must vanish everywhere".

Comment: Which seems to be a different shape/approach than what you suggested. But whatever helps you

Comment: No. It is exactly the same: A tire formed magnet with north on the outside and south on the inside. So again thanks to @ChrisWhite for finding that.