# Magnet arcs assemly

Tags: electromagnetism

Is it possible to join multiple Neodymium magnet arcs (shown blow), which are radially magnetized, to create a cylindrical ring unity that is also radially magnetized?

If it is not possible, how to create such cylindrical ring?

[image: Magnet Arc]
[image: Magnet Ring]

Comment: What law do you suspect would such a magnet violate? Did you see this http://www.neodymium-magnet.org/Neodymium-Arc-Magnet-p147.html?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54615/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that you could produce such a ring by putting individual neodymium magnets next to each other — the inside/south of one would repel the inside/south of its neighbor, and so they'd want to jump around until they were at different radius and the south and north parts could overlap.

However you can certainly produce a ring of radially outward-pointing field: it's called a [quadrupole](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/magquad.html#c2) and you can make it by taking a [Helmholtz coil pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_coil) and reversing the current direction in one coil.  If you had a torus of unmagnetized material, you make a permanent-magnet quadrupole by building a coil pair parallel to the rings of your torus and running it in the reversed configuration to magnetize your sample.

If you really want to assemble a ring of neodymium magnets, you'll need to build a frame to put them in that will keep them from jumping around.  The frame will have to be made of something sturdy but nonmagnetic, like aluminum, and you'll have to be able to clamp the magnets in as you add them one at a time.  My experience suggests that your first frame or two won't work, and that you'll lose some magnets to breakage when they jump out of the frame, so keep that in mind as you're budgeting.

Comment: Yes, this system of magnets would try to minimize the total energy of this field configuration by moving the magnets around, if we let that movement happen. But if we don't, it's quite easy to assemble individual magnets to form this ring. To magnetize a material with a quadrupole configuration, on the other hand, would take an uncomfortably large current and water cooled coils. I would stick to the assembly method for simplicity.

Comment: Would you please inform me how to assemble individual magnets to form this ring?

Comment: Is this by collecting multiple Neodymium magnet arcs of different polarity orientations next to each other?

Comment: @CuriousOne It depends on what the goal of the assembly is. Strong permanent magnets have a surface field of about one tesla, but it falls off quickly with distance.  A current quadrupole will produce lots of field everywhere in space except at the center of the pair. It's not clear what the goal is.

Comment: @rob: The OP was asking explicitly about permanent magnets.

Comment: Then the answer is that it'd be hard, since the magnets won't like to be that way, but not impossible; and that there's no physical law forbidding that assembly because there's a current configuration with the same field; and that the best way to proceed depends what the OP intends to do with this field configuration, which isn't stated. Which is what I tried to say. Please edit if you think I was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look up [Halbach Arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halbach_array)
A Halbach array is a special arrangement of permanent magnets that augments the magnetic field on one side of the array while cancelling the field to near zero on the other side. You may be able to do something similar, depending upon application.

Answer (score 0):

yes its also how to create a magnetic vortex.
https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj3iJj1hd3JAhUJ4iYKHU5LDesQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fthegreaterpicture.com%2Ffree-energy.html&psig=AFQjCNEDKwzXevorPSs_zVuuxfFF_VwFAw&ust=1450240598184220