# Donut shaped magnet

Tags: electromagnetism

Suppose we have a horseshoe magnet. Now we bend it in such a way that it becomes donut shaped and poles remain in contact with each other. In this situation, what will happen to the magnet? Will it still behave as a magnet? Where would be its poles? What will happen to the domains inside the magnet?

Comment: [Related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/54615/what-happens-to-the-magnetic-field-in-this-case).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maxwell's equation $\nabla\cdot\vec{B}=0$ tells us that there are no magnetic monopoles (sources of magnetic "charge"). As a result, magnetic field lines must always form closed loops. Closed loops don't really have a beginning or an end ("poles"), but just a sense of direction (clockwise or counter-clockwise). The poles of a magnet just help to figure out which sense the loops emerging from the magnet posses.

Therefore, if you take a U-shaped magnet and bend it into a donut shape, you are just making another loop. Nothing happens to the domains inside the magnet, and the magnet remains a magnet.

Actually, these types of magnets are used to produce toroidal fields. They have important uses in electronics.

Comment: Toroidal electromagnets, sure, as inductors! But I'm not sure if I've ever seen a *toroidal permanent magnet* doing anything useful or important anywhere though :-)

Comment: @uhoh: Yes, the [ferrite chokes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrite_bead) commonly used today are not permanent magnets. Perhaps N. Charron is referring to core memory? Most computers from about 1955 to 1975 use non-volatile [magnetic-core memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic-core_memory) which is based on magnetizing donut-shaped permanent magnets either clockwise or counterclockwise.

Comment: @DavidCary ah yes, [this stuff](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/12478/12102). Thanks!

Comment: i can only assume the entirety of the magnetic field will be inside the magnet, flowing one direction