# Joining Magnets to Make Larger Uni-Pole

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-monopoles

I would like to know;

1. if it is possible to force magnet wedges (as seen in picture) together to form a "**Uni-Pole Radial Ring Magnet**?"

[image]

2. Also, if it is possible to force smaller "Uni-Pole Radial Ring Magnets" (like the one shown below) together to form a larger one?

[image]

The magnets are neodymium.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15655/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18115/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54615/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, although the tooling might be a challenge.

Please note that it is often easier to use soft iron *pole pieces* (artfully-shaped chunks of metal that are fitted tightly to the magnet faces) to shape the magnetic field lines the way you want them, rather than trying to shape the *magnet itself* to obtain the same result.

Comment: Niels, thank you very much for your response.  
(1) When you say, "it is often easier to use soft iron pole pieces (artfully-shaped chunks of metal that are fitted tightly to the magnet faces) to shape the magnetic field lines the way you want them," are you suggesting that I could use pieces of iron to join the like poles (e.g., North to North and South to South)? 
(2) When magnets are joined like this, (like pole to like pole), does the strength of the newly formed magnet decreases?

Comment: please have a look at a permanent-magnet loudspeaker cross-section to understand what I mean by pole pieces. -NN