# Magnetic empty sphere

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Suppose I have a large supply of small rods that are magnetized, each extremity of the cylinder with the usual N or S magnetic pole. I assemble those small rods into the shell of a hollow sphere, say all S poles pointing towards the center of the sphere. What happens to the magnetic field lines inside and outside the sphere?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the magnetic field inside hollow ball of magnets?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18115/)

Answer (score 0):

In the suggested orientation, the magnets do not make any preferred direction.
By symmetry, only a B-field in a radial direction can be created.   And, for external or internal field, that is impossible (because it would be a magnetic monoopole if there were any nonzero field value).

So, you'd get zero field, except for the small gaps between the rods, and
short distances compared to the gap spacing.    If the 'rods' are allowed
to become microscopic, an interesting thing happens: permanent magnets
(like the rods) are effectively created by a sheet current running around
their cylindrical surfaces (it's electron orbitals and spins, on the
atomic level).   Those currents, if you make a bundle of rods, cancel
everywhere inside the bundle, and  only leave a sheet current running
around the outer bundle surface.

So, fusing magnetized atoms into the sphere as described would cancel
the sheet currents, and demagnetize all the 'rod' elements.   The complete spherical
shell has no 'outer' boundary where a net uncancelled current could flow.

Comment: Is that something we can see from Maxwell's equations? E.g. the divergence of B inside the sphere needs to be 0? And/or can we directly relate the no-border topological property of the sphere to the absence of B inside?

Comment: As for the "sheet currents", we could easily block them by inserting insulators between the rods. Also, magnetic moment is an intrinsic property of the electron, that is not going to vanish. The only way the field would disappear would be for the spins to take random orientations.

Comment: It is possible (according to Maxwell's equations) to make dipole fields with currents.  There is no prohibition of monopoles, other than (1) they have never been observed, and (2) no combination of particles and currents is known that could generate such.   The 'equivalence' of sheet current with atomic spin alignment is just another way of saying that the electrons have no monopole field.

Comment: Doesn't $\nabla B=0$ prohibit magnetic monopoles?

Comment: That one of Maxwell's equations just represents an observation of no magnetic monopoles.  If  we discovered one tomorrow, we'd add a term to the right hand side.  So, it's descriptive, but not proscriptive.   The wikipedia article on 'magnetic monopoles' has more info.