# Is it possible to make a hollow sphere magnet, if so what would the magnetic fields look like?

Tags: magnetic-fields

I have been attempting to have a hollow half sphere magnet made. All manufactures I've contacted have responded with "that shape is impossible". I'm curious if the shape itself is impossible or will the magnet have no magnetic field if created, therefore making it pointless.

[image]

Comment: Which direction do you want the magnetization in? It's certainly possible to magnetize a hollow sphere.

Comment: I guess  you mean magnetized in the radial direction. You could make such hemispheres and force them together, but the fields will cancel.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magnets arranged in a sphere](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15655/magnets-arranged-in-a-sphere)